# Linked AutoCompleteTextView views. Selection in one changes list in other

Tags: android, arrays, multidimensional-array, filter, autocompletetextview

I need to enter a location for a survey. The location consists of a sub place(s) name and a main place name. An example is *Paris* (Sub place) and *France* (main place).

The sub place and main place options are represented in two `AutoCompleteTextView` views. The requirements are that if I select a sub place first the main place is automatically filled in. If I select a main place first the available options in the sub place is filtered to only includes sub places linked to the main place selected. Example for main place *France*, sub place will filter options to *Paris*, *Marseille*, *Lyon* etc.

What kind of data structure should I use for a list of 20000 items each with a sub and main place? It is one to many data set.

- How do I change the available items in an `AutoCompleteTextView` dependent on the input of another `AutoCompleteTextView`?
- How do I implement this kind of problem? I am already seeing load time issues when opening the Activity with 20000 odd items in an `AutoCompleteTextView`.

Any suggestions please.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think performance will be much of a problem. Just save the data in a database, which will provide you with the easiest way for your structure.

Even after the first letter of the main place is pressed, it already drastically reduces possibilities.

Going from sub place --> main place, you could put the treshhold before showing the option list a bit higher.

Comment: How do I assign a sqllite database to an AutoCompleteTextView?

Comment: In the API demo's (in Eclipse new Android project --> Examples) there are multiple examples of AutoCompleteTextView which will use the Contact database with a cursor adapter.